# RunAs under domain account from non-AD Windows

Tags: active-directory, user-management, workgroup, runas

Why does [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/40283/runas-different-user-doesnt-work) tell me it is impossible, and [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/70376/runas-domain-account-still-asks-for-password) states the opposite?

---

Update1:

- http://msgoodies.blogspot.com/2006/04/runas-without-domain-trusts.html

Comment: The answer to the second question has nothing to do with runas.  The answer relates to how IE does authentication.

Comment: Which is the second question? If it is [2], then it tells also about SSMS. They are just exactly 2 and only cases (IE, SSMS) that I, as developer, need, i.e. to runas under domain user from non-domained computer

Comment: @Zoredache, see Update1. It is difficult for me to understand that using/entering RunAs has nothing to do with RunAs. What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 2nd link, the use of `runas` with the `/netonly` switch tells runas to run the specified program and if the program is ever asked for remote authentication to use the supplied credentials. The program is still executed as a local user.

The 1st link has the questioner attempting to actually run the program as a domain user, which will not work([link](https://serverfault.com/questions/174196/workgroup-windows-users-or-groups-can-use-domain-accounts-but-not-vice-versa/174206#174206)).